# Disable message after register

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, messages

How can I disable the messages that appear on the top of the page. For example: 
[image: This one]

The code of the message is this one:
`<ul class="messages">
  <li class="success-msg">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Please wait for your account to be activated</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Obrigado por se registar com Menu.</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>`

Thanks a lot,

Rafael

Comment: I don't know why did you want to remove message but if you want to remove only for registration then you can override customer account controller. and remove message. You can see message there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the controller where message specified as `Please wait for your account to be activated`

**Dirty way:**
Just comment that line in controller

**Standard way:**
1. Create your custom module
2. Override controller
3. Remove message from their

Comment: could someone let me know how to implement "Please wait for your account to be activated". Customer should be able to login only after they are approved by admin

Answer (score 0):

These messages are likely being added by a third-party module. I recommend that you investigate the third-party module to figure out how to make changes to it. Once you figure out where that message is being added, you can then override the controller or use an event to remove it (this is the best way, but may not be easy).